# How to specify defaults for a plugin function in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement a simple plugin system which will allow people to write the following:

```
[Plugin("A plugin function")]
public static int PluginFunction(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

and then drop the DLL containing this function into a folder where it will be scanned by the application and show up as an available function at runtime. This all works fine, so far so good, the PluginAttribute class is what you would expect, just a description string for the function.

However, I'd like to allow the plugin writer to specify default values for the parameters. This is OK for values which are constant at compile time and then deduced via reflection, but I'd like a way to specify defaults for more complex types which will be created at runtime. Has anyone implemented something similar? The primary goal is to make it simple to implement plugin functions - I'm trying to avoid complex scaffolding but accept that my nice simple system is not going to cut it if I want this feature. I'm also happy to have some complexity in the application code which makes the system appear simple to the plugin writer.

Thanks,
Charlie.

---

Update:

I'm going with a combination of what's been suggested here, the closest is what Peter O. came up with - here's a version:

```
[Plugin("A plugin function")]
[Defaults(typeof(AdderDefaults))]
public static int Adder(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

public static class AdderDefaults
{
    public static int a { get { return 1; } }
    public static int b { get { return 2; } }
}

[Plugin("Another plugin function")]
[Defaults(typeof(TexturizerDefaults))]
public static Bitmap Texturize(Bitmap source, Point offset)
{
    return result;
}

public static class TexturizerDefaults
{
    // no default for source parameter
    public static Point offset { get { return new Point(16, 16); } }
}
```

This allows parameters to be skipped and specified by name. No compile time checking but that's OK - checking these at runtime is acceptable.

Comment: Any reason you are recreating [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I've been looking, but can't find the way to do what I want with the MEF, sorry - do you know which MEF piece I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can create an attribute which refers to a type
containing default values for the plugin. Example:

```
[PluginDefaults(typeof(MyPluginDefaults))]
```

The class MyPluginDefaults could then look like:

```
public class MyPluginDefaults {
     int Parameter1 { // First parameter
         get { return 0; } // default value for 'a'
     }
     int Parameter2 { // Second parameter
         get { return 4; } // default value for 'b'
     }
     // Additional parameters would be called Parameter3, Parameter4, and so on.

}
```

Comment: And how do you find out which field is default for which parameter? By their order?

Comment: Exactly, by their order.  The properties for the parameter class are named Parameter1 for the first parameter, Parameter2 for the second parameter, and so on.

Comment: I need them to be able to skip some parameters - ideally they'll specify the defaults by name - this could work by using the names of the methods in the defaults class...

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way to do that, the simpliest is to use a simple convention :

```
[Plugin("A plugin function")]
public static int PluginFunction(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

public static object[] PluginFunctionDefaultArguments()
{
    return new [] { 0, 0 };
}
```

Each time you find a function marked with `PluginAttribute` search for a function having the same name with the `DefaultArguments` sufix, no parameters and an `object[]` return type. Then call it and store the values somewhere. You should also support the default values to be specifed using the dedicated C#/VB syntax (it is found in the [`DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.defaultvalue.aspx) member for the parameter)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have property `Defaults` for each of the classes. It returns an object that can be queried for the defaults, for example like this:

```
object[] pluginFunctionDefaults = FooPlugin.Defaults["PluginFunction"];
```

(Obviously, you wouldn't have code exactly like this in your application.)

And the declaration of the defaults could look like this:

```
class FooPlugin
{
    static FooPlugin()
    {
        var bar = new Bar();

        Defaults = new DefaultValues()
            .Add(() => PluginFunction(42, 13))
            .Add(() => AnotherFunction(bar));
    }

    public static DefaultValues Defaults { get; private set; }

    // actual methods of the class
}
```

Using expressions like this means that the types of the defaults are checked at compile time. The `DefaultValues` class parses the expressions and stores the parameters. It could look something like this:

```
class DefaultValues
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object[]> m_expressions =
        new Dictionary<string, object[]>();

    public DefaultValues Add<T>(Expression<Func<T>> func)
    {
        var methodCall = ((MethodCallExpression)func.Body);
        var name = methodCall.Method.Name;

        var arguments =
            methodCall.Arguments
                .Select(Evaluate)
                .ToArray();

        m_expressions.Add(name, arguments);

        return this;
    }

    private static object Evaluate(Expression expression)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(
            Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(object)))
            .Compile()();
    }

    public object[] this[string methodName]
    {
        get { return m_expressions[methodName]; }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is really cool, I might go with something like this, I'll have a play and see what happens